# What is the iPhone process com.apple.dt.ins?

Tags: ios, xcode

This process is constantly consuming 10% or more of my CPU time on my iPhone 6, however I can't find any mention of what this process is on the internet at all.

My battery is draining fast and appears to be related to this process running, but not knowing what it's responsible for I can't try and debug by disabling settings etc.

Does anyone have any insight onto what this process does on the iPhone?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4mF3iYq.png]

Answer (score 5):

The `dt` looks like it has something to do with the **D**eveloper **T**ools. `ins` may look like **Ins**truments.

Based on your screenshot, the PID seems to indicate that it has been created shortly after the DTMobileIS process, which is responsible for installing the app onto your device on behalf of Xcode (**D**eveloper **T**ools **Mobile I**nstallation **S**ystem, or something along these lines). This confirms that it has something to do with Xcode running your app on-device.

So in my humble opinion, that's the process that gives feedback to Xcode about memory and CPU pressure when you're running your program on-device from Xcode.

Comment: I had a similar hunch, but unplugged the device from the computer (and thus Xcode), restarted, and still the process shows up if I use a process monitor app from the app store on the phone. However, that's not to say it isn't always running on a developer device - it bothers me that it is always using 20% of the CPU... constantly, even if not connected to Xcode.